# How to see unicode values in GAE Development Console Datastore Viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Unicode strings are stored in GAE datastore as part of list. In result, page like `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore/edit?key=...` shows values there like

```
[u'latin characters', u'\u0432\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432']
```

So, I can not read there what is hidden under second string. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

long-term solution: file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry
short-term solution: use Python:

```
"""
>>> print u'\u0432\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432'.encode('utf-8')
владимиров
"""
```

FWIW, the same print command will work in the interactice console:
http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive